# How to add Edit and Print button in Jquery DataTable?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, datatable

I successfully installed datatable in my html page using AJax and PHP:

```
$("#btn_ca_vanrental").click(function(){
    var oTable= $('#jsontable_vanrental').dataTable(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'proc_php/get_vanrental.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(s){
            oTable.fnClearTable();
            for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
             oTable.fnAddData([
                        s[i][0],
                        s[i][1],
                        s[i][2],
                        s[i][3]                                     
                               ]);                                      
            } // End For                                            
        },
        error: function(e){
           alert(e.responseText);   
        }
        });
});
```

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php
    require_once('../connection/auth.php');
    require_once('../connection/connection.php');

    $query = mysql_query("select id,date_filed,purpose,total from tblcasalaryform");
    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
        $output[] = array ($fetch[0],$fetch[1],$fetch[2],$fetch[3]);
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

So far it is working fine, but I want to add another table column for the user to have an option to edit and print the certain entry. How?

Here's my HTML:

```
<table id="jsontable_salary" class="display table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr width="5%">
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Purpose</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>             
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Purpose</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to play around with DataTables for a very limited time last year for a project and it's very handy but a bit overwhelming.

**Just to give you an idea** the way I implemented the same problem you got here, I used ['columnDefs'](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) or just '**columns**' property within DataTables to render my data, like so:

```js
/* Init DataTables */
var oTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
  "data": <?= $data;?>,
  // ... some more configurations here
  "columnDefs": [
    {
      data: null,
      className: 'actions-column', // Class to lookup to in Html table for insert
      searchable: false,
      "render": function(data, type, row) { // Available data available for you within the row
        return "<a href='#' class='print-button'>Print</a>&nbsp;<a href='#' class='edit-button'>Edit</a>";
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

and in my Html where '**actions-column**' exists:

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- ... some more th here -->
      <th class="actions-column"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

All you have to do is bind events in each button click to do what is needed. I hope it gives you an idea to get the functionality going. Cheers!

---

By the way, with regards to editing, there is an extension called [Editor](https://editor.datatables.net/), that lets you do couple of ways to edit a row, but I'm afraid it's not free.

I grabbed some code snippet(for inline editing) from their  to give you some more ideas:

```js
// Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
$('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
  editor.inline( this );
} );
```

For printing and other data imports/saving they also have [Table Tools](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/)

Comment: How do I integrate it in my datatable? I tried it but nothing came up. I think my JQuery structure is different from yours.

Comment: Yes theres a big difference on how we implemented it but if you notice the option "data": <?= $data;?>, $data variable is from my database and assign it to dataTable data option.